# Where can I find a list of all parameters/variables used in Postfix master.cf?

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

In postfix master.cf, there are entries like this (for dovecot):

```
dovecot unix - n n - - pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -n -m ${extension}
```

As far as i understand it, variables like `${sender}`, `${user}`, `${nexthop}`, `${extension}` are provided by postfix, but I was not able to find documentation of a list of all possible parameters. I need to know if there are more variables than these... As I have problems setting up my system as intended. I am looking for a variable that represents the mapping for an email to a virtual mailbox-username...

If someone knows where I can find such a list, I would be very thankfull!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you see, the command name is `pipe`. This is a postfix built-in way to deliver mails to an external program, in this case dovecot.

The accepted parameters as well as the available variables are documented in its [man page](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html).

Comment: Hello Holger, Thanks ver much!!! I was not aware of that pipe is the command. I thought this is solely related to master (and in the master man page I had not found anything). Thanks very much, your answer made verything clear and was what i was looking for. thanks!